# getting the second occurrence of a substring with PatIndex

Tags: sql, substring, patindex

With this query I get the postal code from an address and it works, but there are some cases where the address number's length is 5 and so I get this instead of the postal code, is there any chance to get the last occurrence with PatIndex?

```
SELECT address,IIF((PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', address)>0), substring(address, PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', address), 5) , NULL) AS postalCode
from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the LAST occurrence

1. Reverse address
2. Find first match `PatIndex` in reversed address
3. Reverse the first matching substring

Thus

```
SELECT address,IIF((PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', address)>0), reverse(substring(reverse(address), PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', reverse(address)), 5)) , NULL) AS postalCode
from tbl
```

[Run with db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc9696dff54fc5345b98c67cfff2673c)